# How can I swap jQuery.ajax call with jquery-less XmlHttpRequest way?

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Can you please help me to swap the jQuery ajax call below with XmlHttpRequest so that jQuery is not needed?
(Would I also  need to swap:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

when I don't use jQuery.ajax but XmlHttpRequest? )

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 

var endpointAddress = "http://My.Server.FooService/FooServices.svc/";
var url = endpointAddress + "/SubmitFoo";
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Foo submitted succesfully!");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert('Error Occured' + errorThrown);
                }
            }               //eof ajax object
        );  //eof .ajax
    }
```

Comment: Why replace `$.ajax` (complete with CORS support) with something with worse API and not cross-browser-compatible?

Comment: Indeed, `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't work cross-browser, use a library like jQuery, prototype, etc

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't want to include jQuery?

Comment: Because the server where the html sits, when jQuery.support.cors = true;  is called nothing happens and the javascript stops instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Making cross domain JavaScript requests using XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html)